# MessageQueue.BeginReceive TimeSpan timeout

Tags: .net, msmq

Trying to find out what is the max value for the subject and also the default value

cant seem to find this info anywhere

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a timespan, the maximum timeout is UInt32.MaxValue, which is set using `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(UInt32.MaxValue)` or a bit over 49.7 days. Looking at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/MessageQueue.cs

````
        {
            long timeoutInMilliseconds = (long)timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
            if (timeoutInMilliseconds < 0 || timeoutInMilliseconds > UInt32.MaxValue)
                throw new ArgumentException(Res.GetString(Res.InvalidParameter, "timeout", timeout.ToString()));```
````

Answer (score 0):

The default for MessageQueue.BeginReceive is "no timeout".

The maximum value for MessageQueue.BeginReceive(TimeSpan) will depend on which TimeSpan you use. For example, using a 'ticks' TimeSpan means a maximum of 922,337,203,685.5 seconds (nearly 30,000 years).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx1zzcwy(v=vs.110).aspx
How do you set no time out here?

You cant use the a very high value of TimeSpan in message queue.  I think think the max is less than a day.  I've tested it

Comment: Slawekwin linked to the method documentation. Calling BeginReceive() "initiates an asynchronous receive operation that has no time-out."

Comment: "I think the max is less than a day. I've tested it." What was the test?

Comment: The link doesn't answer my q.  Overloads are expecting a timeout value  The test was me setting high values and getting a run-time error.  Test for yourself